# How to pull last cell in column using openpyxl in python

Tags: python, openpyxl

I created a small program that writes to an excel file.  I have another program that needs to read the last entry (in column A) every day.  Since there is a new data imported into the excel file every day, the cell that I need to capture is different.

I'm looking to see if there is a way for me to grab the last cell in Column A using openpyxl in python?

I don't have much experience with this, so I wasn't sure where to start.

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('text.xlsx')

sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html
try this, it should get the entire A column and take the last entry:

```py
sheet['A'][-1]
```